# Errors adding dependencies with Carthage: "Unsupported architecture"

Tags: ios, carthage

I am pretty new using Carthage. I am using as dependency manager for my iOS app. I am trying to add RXSwift and SwiftEventBus. So this is my Cartfile:

```
github "cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus" == 1.1.0
github "ReactiveX/RxSwift" ~> 2.0
```

Running the update command, I got these errors and I don't really understand where is the problem.

```
*** Cloning RxSwift
*** Cloning SwiftEventBus
*** Checking out RxSwift at "2.2.0"
*** Checking out SwiftEventBus at "1.1.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/7n/94jxf5bj7zx9qblwljn64s080000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.dIWeah.log
*** Building scheme "RxTests-OSX" in Rx.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "RxBlocking-tvOS" in Rx.xcworkspace
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
ld: warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest
ld: warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftXCTest.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: error: Unsupported architecture
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'; did you mean 'uint64_t'?
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h:30:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_intptr_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:42:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h:30:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_size_t'; did you mean '__darwin_ino_t'?
<unknown>:0: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:10: error: could not build module 'Darwin'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CoreFoundation'
A shell task failed with exit code 65:
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```